# has_many :through not giving access to <class>_id from base

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-many-through, railscasts

Model code

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :day_tokens, :name, :address, :phone
  has_many :locavailability
  has_many  :dayavailables, :through => :locavailability
  attr_reader :day_tokens
  def day_tokens=(ids)
    self.locavailability.dayavailable_id= ids.split(",")
  end
end

class Dayavailable < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :locavailability
  has_many  :locations, :through => :locavailability
end

class Locavailability < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dayavailable_id, :location_id
  belongs_to :dayavailable
  belongs_to :location
end
```

Database Columns:

```
locations: id, name, address, phone, hours, created_at, updated_at
dayavailables: id, day, time, created_at, updated_at
locavailabilities: id, location_id, dayavailable_id, created_at, updated_at
```

**Error**

```
irb(main):004:0> l = Location.find(1)
=> #<Location id: 1, name: "test", address: "123 Fake Street", phone: "23443234324", hours: "M-F 9 - 5", created_at: "2011-05-16 04:56:31", updated_at: "2011-05-16 04:56:31">
irb(main):005:0> l.class
=> Location(id: integer, name: string, address: string, phone: string, hours: string, dentistry_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
irb(main):006:0> l.locavailability
=> []
irb(main):007:0> l.dayavailable_id
NoMethodError: undefined method `dayavailable_id' for #<Location:0xb6af7c40>
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activemodel-3.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:364:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:44:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:44:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):6
```

Shouldn't Location class have access to `dayavailable_id`?? I am going by the code in railscasts episode 258 on [github](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/blob/master/episode-258/bookstore/app/models/book.rb)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `Location` should have access to `dayavailable_id`?
The `dayavailable_id` is column of `locavailabilities`, if you given true:

> Database Columns:
>
> locations: id, name, address, phone, hours, created_at, updated_at
>
> dayavailables: id, day, time, created_at, updated_at
>
> **locavailabilities**: id, location_id, **dayavailable_id**, created_at, updated_at

Try this:
**UPDATED**

```
l = Location.find(1)
l.dayavailable_ids #=> Returns an array of the associated objects’ ids
```

But if you call `dayavailable_id`, it should be a column of table.

So `l.dayavailable_ids` will execute this DB query:

```
select id from dayavailables d
inner join locavailabilities l on l.dayavailable_id = d.id 
where l.location_id = 1
```

but Locavailability.find(1).dayavailable_id will execute this DB query(not really, only for more readable):

```
select dayavailable_id from locavailabilities l
where l.location_id = 1
```

Comment: as you can see from my console output, `l.locavailability` returns an array `[]`.  I can not call `dayavailable_id` on it.  Furthermore, as shown in the github link, their the author _is_ calling in same fashion as me.

Comment: I do see a typo now though. the author on github code is adding `s` at the end of `id`, however, I am not. I would want to try that but will that really make a difference? Can't try it for a while since I'm not near home computer :(

Comment: sweet. explaining the problem to someone worked out much better than staring at the code to find out why the heck it wasn't working.